# selected link changes background

Tags: javascript

I have 2 menus, category and countries. I've made so far to change and keep background of one element but I have problem with simultaneous memory of other menu's element.

```
var lookaround=[];

function seleItem(obj,color){
    if(lookaround[obj.className])
        lookaround[obj.className].style.background=null;
    lookaround[obj.className]=obj;
    obj.style.background=color;
}
```

Example page is [HERE](http://lookaroundyou.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an object instead of an array for lookaround:

```
var lookaround = {};
```

Comment: i made it work. upper code is fine, problem was in php script. thanks